# Porting a C++ application to android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libstdc++

Is it possible to port a C++ application which uses the STL extensively to Android? I understand that currently the NDK does not support this, but is there any effort (open source or otherwise) underway to achieve this?

If not is there a way to cross compile libstdc++ for Android?

UPDATE: 
Ndk Revision 5 promises a default STL implementation based on STLport. 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/gingerbread-ndk-awesomeness.html [Read this official NDK blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/gingerbread-ndk-awesomeness.html), http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html>and the revision notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to start with [Dmitry Moskalchuk's modified version of the NDK](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r3.php) (includes support for exceptions, RTTI, and the standard c++ library).  Keep in mind that if you go down this path your application's size will be larger as you will be statically linking a c++ library into it.  Also, [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/d78d1304eea42825/) from the andriod-ndk group may give better direction on how to incorporate the STL.

Comment: That is a trade off which I am willing to make for this particular use case. This looks quite promising.

Comment: Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Donal: It does not look too good. Seeing seg faults while doing push_back on vector elements. Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement what you need yourself. The STL is only written using the CRT, OS headers and standard C++. It would depend on what you need done.