# Porting C++ application to Android using NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to port an C++ application to Android using the NDK. The application is to be used in both Win-PCs and tablets (Project Tango). Its function is to support a custom API that I am testing. The applications are for research purposes only, so I am not worried about deployment other than on said tablets.

I know that the NDK support of C++ libs has evolved substantially since this question: [Porting a C++ application to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725997/porting-a-c-application-to-android)

The application I am porting depends on the following headers: 
STL containers, pthreads32, jsoncpp, winsocks.

I know winsocks will have to be rewritten to BSD sockets, what about STLs and pthreads? Will jsoncpp work if I have the complete library?

Also, what is the process for including other libraries? Do I just include the .so file? Apologies, I am very new to the NDK.

Comment: You do not seem to understand what you are asking about. *"I know winsocks will have to be rewritten to standard c++"* is pure nonsense. There is no standard C++ sockets (yet).

Comment: @SergeyA: Ok, let me rephrase that. I will write it using BSD sockets. Happy now?

Comment: At least makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL support is documented here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Can include prebuilt libraries into your app with https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html